# Эффект ripple некорректно работает на Android 9 (Api 28, Pie)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Всем привет!
Такой вопрос. Настроил эффект ripple на кнопку. На всех версиях Android работает корректно: когда нажимаю на кнопку, она немного подсвечивается, затем, когда отпускаю кнопку, происходит небольшая рябь. 
 На Android 9 работает наполовину: кнопка подсвечивается, но когда кнопку отпускаю, ряби нет.
 Кто нибудь сталкивался с этим? Как можно исправить?

Так выглядит background моей кнопки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/primary_button_ripple_effect">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:endColor="@color/start_color_for_primary_button_passive"
                android:startColor="@color/end_color_for_primary_button_passive"
                android:type="linear"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/custom_button_radius"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_button_radius"
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/custom_button_radius"
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/custom_button_radius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!